# crawl excel data automatically based on contents

Tags: julia, xlsx

I want to get data from many excel files with the same format like this:

[image: sample XLSX file]

What I want is to output the `ID` data from column B to a CSV file. I have many files like this and for each file, the number of columns may not be the same but the `ID` data will always be in the B column.

Is there a package in Julia that can crawl data in this format? If not, what method should I use?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [XLSX package](https://github.com/felipenoris/XLSX.jl).

If the file in your screenshot is called `JAKE.xlsx` and the data shown is in a sheet called `DataSheet`:

```
data = XLSX.readtable("JAKE.xlsx", "DataSheet")

# `data[1]` is a vector of vectors, each with data for a column.
# that way, `data[1][2]` correponds to column B's data.
data[1][2]
```

This should give you access to a vector with the data you need. After getting the `ID`s into a vector, you can use the [CSV package](https://juliadata.github.io/CSV.jl/stable/#Examples-1) to create an output file.

If you add a sample xlsx file to your post it might be possible to give you a more complete answer.